# Selenium Grid, Capturing Screenshots

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Capture screenshot using selenium command captureScreenshottoText or capture screenshot works fine if display/monitor is ON
But if Monitor is OFF it captures blank/Black images

How to get Proper images when display is off

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the session is locked out or when the machine goes to sleep mode. Workaround that we use is to make sure that the machine never goes into this state. You can find more details here on how to disable the screen lock - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disableenable-lock-workstation-functionality-windows-l/

Comment: It happens when monitor is off but how to get valid images even if monitor is off

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to a remote computer, use a VNC server/viewer to open your Selenium Server so that the display doesn't get killed. If you are using Remote Desktop, the display will close whenever you quit.

Connecting via VNC should fix your issues